# Transaction-Style HTTP requests

Tags: sql, http, transactions, atomic

I recently ran into such problem:

For each user, I need to do the following on server side:

```
First
(SQL)  Insert user's record with a Unique constraint on ID
Then Parallel
(Http) Subscribe user to Service A, get subscription_id_A
(Http) Subscribe user to Service B, get subscription_id_B
Finally
(SQL)  Update user's record with both subscription ids
```

Ideally I want this entire operation to be transactional, eg if any of http requests or sql fails, it would be as if nothing happened. Added: if Request A fails but B succeeds, I would be stuck: Do I cancel the transaction and end up with an untracked subscription or do I commit it and end up with user missing a subcription

Given that this is likely impossible to achieve, what would be the next best thing I can do?

The service A and B does provide APIs to check for existence of subscriptions and to modify, delete a subscription too, but I want to avoid the Check Then Act style. The SQL server has highest isolation level

Comment: *"Given that this is likely impossible to achieve"* - It certainly is not. It's actually trivially easy. Run a `START TRANSACTION` before you do all those things, and a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` after you're done. If anything goes wrong inbetween, run `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. Done.

Comment: That is the easy part, but the problem is if request to Service A succeeds and request to Service B fails, if I cancel the transaction then I would end up with an untrack subscription A

Comment: Of course it's your duty to roll back any external transactions you started. I take it there will be a way to cancel `A` with another HTTP request?

Comment: The real question is - why should it be impossible for a user to exist *without* a subscription? I don't see why that would be an error. Creating a user should be orthogonal to adding subscriptions to it.

Comment: Yeh that's what I am aksing here, is there a best practice guide to this kind of problems, I am sure people run into them all the time, deleting a subscription with another request can make things quite complicated, what if the transaction.commit fails, do I delete both subscriptions or retry the transaction, what if the deletion fails..uh

Comment: the reason for this is that..I am in a team and we use azure mobile service with javascript backend, so we don't have too much control, the entire thing is supposed to be as simple as one APi call, duplicate subscriptions would be very bad as user would be getting duplicate messages, missing subscription is also bad cuz we need both services to work togerther

Comment: What kind of JavaScript backend are you using?

Comment: It would be Node with Express, but we have very limited control over it tho

Comment: General idea: Abstract the subscription process into an object that provides subscribe() and unsubscribe() methods, both returning promises. Open a transaction. Create the user, create N subscription objects, wait on their overall fulfillment with Promise.all(). On overall success, commit the SQL transaction. on (partial) failure rollback the SQL transaction and unsubscribe all subscriptions that have succeded.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a standard problem. (Often, developers are not aware of this problem and only find out in production.) There is no standard solution. It is impossible to solve in general (see the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem - two systems can never agree with 100% certainty on whether they should commit or abort).

Maybe you can perform all the SQL work first. Insert the user but without subscription IDs. You then try to add the subscriptions one by one and add their IDs in separate transactions once you got them.

Install a background job that periodically checks for users that have been created a long time ago but that do not have subscriptions yet. If you find any discrepancies fix them and log this fact.

This periodic cleanup ensures that temporary failures (which *will* occur due to network glitches, timeouts, redeployments, bugs, ...) are temporary. It also ensures that they are being detected and reported to developers if you like.

This would be an eventually consistent system. The idea is to first transactionally record the *target state* (the user and the goal to create two subscriptions) and then have a background job try to converge the data to the target state.